# how do i use loop in select query

Tags: php, arrays, loops, select, for-loop

How do I use loop in select query? *Query only fetch* one Row, at a time, from Select Query. I want to fetch multiple rows In the Select Query but through a loop

**Select ID**

```
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
function get_id($id){
    $result1=mysql_query("select * from products where id='$id'") 
    or die("Id Problem"."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
    $results1= array();
    $k=0; // add the new line
    while($row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){
        $results1[] = $row1['id'];
        $k++;
    }
    return $results1;
}
```

**Pid Array**

```
 $pid1=get_id($id);
 <?php 
     $max1=count($pid1);
     for($n=0; $n<$max1; $n++)
     {?>
         <input type="hidden" name="pid[]" value="<?php echo $pid1[$n]?>" />
 <?php }?>
```

**Pid Session**

```
$_SESSION['pid']=$_POST['pid'];
```

**I want `fetch` Multiple Rows In Select Query But through Loop**

```
<?php 
$pid = join(',',$_SESSION['pid']); 
$result=mysql_query("SELECT id AS wid FROM mywishlist 
where pid='$pid'") 
or die("Id     Problem"."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
$results= array();
$i=0; // add the new line
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $results[$i] = $row['wid'];
    $i++;
}
echo $results;

$max=count($results);
for($j=0; $j<$max; $j++)
{
?>
    <input type="text" name="wid[]" value="<?php echo $results[$j]; ?>" />
<?php }?>
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: @SLaks sory to say but i don't understand ?

Comment: @FarhanDharsi you're using a loop .. what is the problem?

Comment: @ExplosionPills when i echo $max=count($results); it showing only one row i want to fetch all rows in loop

Comment: @FarhanDharsi how do you know that the table doesn't only have one row?

Comment: @ExplosionPills inserting values into mysql database...

Comment: http://xkcd.com/327/ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: @SLaks you mean by this <input type="text" name="wid[]" value="<?php echo $results[$j]; ?>" />?

Comment: @FarhanDharsi: No; that's an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: Besides security issues, your script seems to run just fine. Did you actually check your databse through some other tool to see if you really have more than one row?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing some things the hard way, tracking and controlling things that would run fine on autopilot.  For example - for loops require you to know the length while foreach loops just run 'til they're done.

Letting PHP take care of the array index by using [] instead of assigning the index will also save you some effort. And since each of your loops really only does one thing, they don't really need braces.

```
$result=mysql_query('SELECT id AS wid FROM mywishlist where pid="'.$pid.'"') or die(); 
$results= array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    $results[]=$row['wid'];
foreach($results as $wid)
    echo '<input type="text" name="wid[]" value="'.$wid.'" />';
```

Of course, you could eliminate one of these loops because they both essentially handle the same data...

```
$result=mysql_query('SELECT id AS wid FROM mywishlist where pid="'.$pid.'"') or die(); 
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    echo '<input type="text" name="wid[]" value="'.$row['wid'].'" />';
```

Furthermore, reidentifying the key from id to wid doesn't make much sense.  Since there is only 1 field in the result, why bother identifying it - we can just fetch the row.

```
$result=mysql_query('SELECT id FROM mywishlist where pid="'.$pid.'"') or die(); 
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
    echo '<input type="text" name="wid[]" value="'.$row[0].'" />';
```

Ooh, let's do it in 2 lines

```
$result=mysql_query('SELECT id FROM mywishlist where pid="'.$pid.'"') or die(); 
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)) echo '<input type="text" name="wid[]" value="'.$row[0].'" />';
```